# Error while Multiple Statements in a Java EE application using NEO4J-JDBC-Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, cypher

Stack: TOMEE / NEO4J 2.1.6 Community Edition

What I am doing:

- Posting an array of JSON objects to a Java JAX-RS Web Service
- Parsing the JSON and creating the Cypher Queries
- Trying execute the Cypher Queries and return the result in JSON.

Problem:

To avoid Duplicate Node creation, without adding additional overheads in the application code, I am using "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON"

This is what my Cypher Looks Like

```
CREATE (EVENTS:Events {name:'nm_Events',value:'256',label:'lb_Events'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (EVENTS:Events) ASSERT EVENTS.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE (LOGOUTS:Logouts {name:'nm_Logouts',value:'4',label:'lb_Logouts'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (LOGOUTS:Logouts) ASSERT LOGOUTS.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE (ACCIDENTAL_CLICKS:Accidental_Clicks {name:'nm_AccidentalClicks',value:'4',label:'lb_AccidentalClicks'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (ACCIDENTAL_CLICKS:Accidental_Clicks) ASSERT ACCIDENTAL_CLICKS.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE (INTERACTIONS:Interactions {name:'nm_Interactions',label:'lbl_interactions'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (INTERACTIONS:Interactions) ASSERT INTERACTIONS.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE (BUTTONS:Buttons {name:'nm_buttons',label:'lbl_buttons'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (BUTTONS:Buttons) ASSERT BUTTONS.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE (GROUP_BUTTON:Group_Button {name:'nm_GroupButton',value:'54',label:'lb_GroupButton'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (GROUP_BUTTON:Group_Button) ASSERT GROUP_BUTTON.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE (DELETE_BUTTON:Delete_Button {name:'nm_DeleteButton',value:'454',label:'lb_DeleteButton'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (DELETE_BUTTON:Delete_Button) ASSERT DELETE_BUTTON.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE (LOGIN_BUTTON:Login_Button {name:'nm_LoginButton',value:'256',label:'lb_LoginButton'} )  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (LOGIN_BUTTON:Login_Button) ASSERT LOGIN_BUTTON.name IS UNIQUE 
CREATE UNIQUE (LOGOUTS)-[:CHILD_OF]->(EVENTS) 
CREATE UNIQUE (ACCIDENTAL_CLICKS)-[:CHILD_OF]->(EVENTS) 
CREATE UNIQUE (DELETE_BUTTON)-[:CHILD_OF]->(GROUP_BUTTON) 
CREATE UNIQUE (GROUP_BUTTON)-[:CHILD_OF]->(BUTTONS) 
CREATE UNIQUE (LOGIN_BUTTON)-[:CHILD_OF]->(BUTTONS) 
CREATE UNIQUE (BUTTONS)-[:CHILD_OF]->(INTERACTIONS)
```

ISSUE:

While executing in NEO4J's console it gives an error

```
Invalid input 'N': expected 'p/P' (line 2, column 20)
"CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (EVENTS:Events) ASSERT EVENTS.name IS UNIQUE "
                    ^
```

I read that you cannot execute multi-line statements in the console but same issue when using the JDBC code.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix DML and DDL, create the constraints / indexes upfront and the data later.

Also in the console each is an individual statement and transaction, if you want to doe the same with JDBC, run over the list of statements in a loop an execute them individually.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I separated them and used loops to execute them separately.